# Is there any Ruby rspec tags equivalent in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

In Ruby Rspec, we can specify tags as follows:

```
it "test 1" :production => true do
    # test something
end
```

Then you can filter tests you want to run using the `--tag production` option.

I am wondering if Mocha in Nodejs has something similar? If not, what would be a good approach achieving this. So far I can only think of adding specific pattern in the title and using `--grep` option.

Edit:

I ended up using https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Tagging,

```
it("test 1 @production", function (done) {
    // test something
})
```

Then run using the `--grep @production` option.

The only downside is @production is part of the title, which makes the report not so clean, especially if you have tags.